# Payment token becomes undefined after the Apple Pay process

Tags: react-native, applepay

I am developing an Apple Pay with react-native. I configured everything and I used [react-native-paymen](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments)t component. Here is my code:

```
onPressApplePay=()=>{
    console.log("1- start Apple Pay");
    if (!DataManager.getInstance().isConnected()) {
       this.myAlert(I18n.t("NoInternetConnectionState"));
       return;
    }

    const DETAILS = {
    id: 'basic-example',

     displayItems: [
       {
         label: 'items',
         amount: { currency: 'EUR', value: '2' },
       },
     ],
     total: {
       label: 'MyApp',
       amount: { currency: 'EUR', value: '2' },
     },

      };

      const METHOD_DATA = [{
         supportedMethods: ['apple-pay'],
         data: {
           merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.myapp',
           supportedNetworks: [ 'mastercard', 'visa'],
           countryCode: 'IT',
           currencyCode: 'EUR'
         }
       }];
     const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS);

     console.log("2- paymentRequest.show", paymentRequest);
     paymentRequest.show()
     .then((paymentResponse) => {
       const { paymentToken } = paymentResponse.details; // On Android, you need to invoke the `getPaymentToken` method to receive the `paymentToken`.

       paymentRequest.canMakePayments()
  .then(canMakePayments => {
    console.log("canMakePayments", canMakePayments);
      console.log("paymentToken", paymentToken);

    // Show fallback payment method
  });

     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("4- err", err);
       console.log("5- paymentRequest", err);
       //alert("The apple pay cancel");
       // The API threw an error or the user closed the UI
     });
```

The problem is that as I try to execute the Apple Pay, it says that the 'Payment is not completed' and the token becomes undefined. Can you please ket me know where the problem might be hiden. 
I should mention that I tried this code on a real device using both real card and sandBox and in all cases it was failed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is also working with stripe and Braintree. The problem was that I needed to add a gateway and a public key which in my case it provided from stripe.

```
const METHOD_DATA = [{
         supportedMethods: ['apple-pay'],
         data: {
           merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.yyyy.xxxx',
           supportedNetworks: [ 'mastercard'],
           countryCode: 'IT',
           currencyCode: 'EUR',
           paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: {
            parameters: {
             gateway: 'stripe',
             'stripe:publishableKey': 'pk_test_XXXXXXX',
             'stripe:version': '5.0.0' // Only required on Android
          }
        }
      }
   }];
```

Then I installed the following add on:

```
yarn add react-native-payments-addon-stripe
yarn add react-native-payments-cli
yarn react-native-payments-cli -- link stripe
```

(You also need the `Carthage update` there to make them work)

Then I made an account in stripe.com and use the publish key of that and finally it works!! 
Also I have added  `paymentResponse.complete('success');` to show the successful payment at the end. Without that it sucks in a loop of waiting and finally shows 'Payment is not complete'.
Now I have a successful message with a nice token!

**I should mention that in the case that you don't use stripe or Braintree, you will not see any token and it will be always undefined. It is natural, so don't worry. You just need to pass `paymentResponse.details` as a JSON to your bank provider and it will work. Because in that case the transactionid will be important which you have it.**

After that, you go through these steps of installing from this [link](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments) . You also need to do these steps regarded to certificates for Apple Pay:

1- First on your App ID in your apple developer account you should enable the Apple Pay with the merchant ID.

2- Then you need to ask from your bank for a certificate on you merchant which is a file that looks like this:
    XXXXX.certSigningRequest.txt

3- Then select your app ID and go to Apple Pay section which was enabled in step one and upload the certificate there.

Done! Your Apple Pay will work.

Answer (score 1):

The mention saved me! I didn't realize that it was normal the token would be nil if you aren't using Stripe/Braintree!